# Can element of a set be a logical sentence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

Let $A$ be a set. Is there a set $B$ whose elements are these elements $x \in A$ which are logical sentences?

Such a set would be constructed using the axiom of specification, provided that $$\phi(x) : x \ \text{is a logical statement}$$
is a propositional function. In the textbook I am studying now (Kazimierz Kuratowski - Introduction to Set Theory) the concept of propositional function is defined so vaguely that I can't decide if this is true.

Comment: Yes; we may have $\{ x \mid x \text { is a propositional formula } \}$. In propo logic we usually define e.g. $\text {Prop} =$ the set of propositional formulas.

Comment: It is well-known that there is no set which contains all sets. My intuition is that quite similarly there should not exist a set of all sentences or all propositional functions. If such set existed, I could just get the set I want to construct here by intersecting $A$ with the set of all logical statements.

Comment: Logical formulas are mathematical object built from sets of symbols using recursive rules. You need to think of them as mathematical objects that can be formalized by encoding as sets, like any other mathematical object. The collection of all formulas in some fixed language with a set of symbols forms a set. If the language has a proper class of symbols, it is a proper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [propositional function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_function) is what we get from a sentence of our language, like e.g. "Socrates is a philosopher" removing the name Socrates and using instead a "place holder" : a variable like $x$.

The resulting expression : "$x$ is a philosopher", is like a mathematical function: assigning to $x$ a "value" : Plato, Napoleon, what we get is a sentence : either true (for Plato) or false (for Napoleon).

In predicate logic, a propositional function $\phi(x)$ is called : [open formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_formula).

See : Kazimierz Kuratowski & Andrzej Mostowski, *Set theory*, North Holland (1968), page 45 :

> we shall consider *propositional functions*. They are expressions which contain
>   variables. If each variable is replaced by the name of an arbitrary element, 
>   then the propositional function becomes a sentence. For instance,
>
> > $x> 0, x^2 < 5, X$ is a non-empty set
>
> are examples of propositional functions. By substitution we obtain, e.g., 
>   the following sentences:
>
> > $1 > 0, 25 < 5$, the set of prime numbers is a non-empty set.

An open formula $\phi(x)$ is what is used in the [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate) :

> $\{ x \mid \phi(x) \}$

to define a set: the set of all and only those objects such that $\phi(x)$ holds of them.

---

Regarding propositional calculus, we satrt with a *language* (or alphabet), i.e. a set of propositional symbols : $p_0,p_1,\ldots$ and the *connectives* : $\lor, \land, \lnot$.

We define *expressions* as finite strings of symbols.

Finally, we have :

> The set $\text {Prop}$ of propositional formulas [also : well-formed formulas]  is the smallest set $X$ with the properties :
>
> > *(i)* $p_i ∈ X$,
> >
> > *(ii)* if $ϕ,ψ ∈ X$, then $(ϕ ∨ ψ), (ϕ \land ψ) ∈ X$,
> >
> > *(iii)* if $ϕ ∈ X$, then $(¬ϕ) ∈ X$.